How to generate IR using avx intrinsics using llvm?
I am using llvm to generate IR.
For example, for the following C code:
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        A[i] =B[i] + 1;
    }

I can generate IR using
clang -O3 -S -emit-llvm   test.c -o  test.ll


The IR file contains instructions like:
%94 = add nsw <8 x i32> %84, <i32 2, i32 2, i32 2, i32 2, i32 2, i32 2, i32 2, i32 2>

This is the SIMD instruction in LLVM IR.
How can I generate IR with AVX simd intrinsics?

What happens if you compile source code that calls the intrinsics?
